# Find DIV with multiple classes and id

Tags: php, foreach, simple-html-dom

I am using Simple `HTML DOM` and I am trying to get a certain element which holds both an ID and a set of classes like this:

```
<div id="leadtxt" class="caption"></div>

foreach($html->find('div #leadtxt .caption', 0) as $element) 
       echo $element->outertext;
```

According to the documentation this should get me the div that has id `#leadtxt` and also has class `.caption` 
 The problem is that it doesn't. How should I write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will try to find an element with the class of `caption` ***within*** the element with the ID of `leadtxt`. Since you have an ID, and IDs must be unique, it would make more sense to simply use that:

```
$html->find('#leadtxt', 0)
```

The exact answer to your question would be this:

```
$html->find('div#leadtxt.caption', 0)
```

Note the lack of space - it'll find the div element with the ID of `leadtxt` and the class of `caption`. But again, this is redundant and the above approach would be better and most likely faster.

**Edit:** here are some further examples as I'm not clear on exactly what you are trying to do.

The following would find all elements which have the ID of `leadtxt` **or** the class of `caption`:

```
$html->find('#leadtxt, .caption')
// OR specify the fact you only want DIV elements...
$html->find('div#leadtxt, div.caption')
```

This would specify you want elements with ANY of the given classes (one or more):

```
$html->find('.classone, .classtwo, .classthree')
// OR just the DIV elements with any of these classes:
$html->find('div.classone, div.classtwo, div.classthree')
```

This would specify any elements with ALL the given classes:

```
$html->find('.classone.classtwo.classthree')
// OR again, just DIV elements...
$html->find('div.classone.classtwo.classthree')
```

**Edit 2:** as you have already said, it seems Simple HTML DOM fails whenever you provide a selector which specifies multiple classes/IDs together. I can only assume that is a weakness in the library which has not yet been addressed. Its a shame, as it means it does **not** work with the standard CSS selectors given above, despite claiming to.

Comment: Have you tried both approaches? What happens? The top one ought to work assuming your HTML does actually contain that ID (once).

Comment: The top one obviously works but its about elements with multiple references; classes and id. Give me a minute, I will make an example on compile online

Comment: It seems 'compile online' doesnt have a 'save' option and 'PHP fiddle' doesnt allow this kind of scraping...sorry you just have to trust me on this:)

Comment: I really don't understand what the problem is. Why would you make an unnecessarily specific selector which will make no difference besides being less efficient? Can I confirm that you are looking for **the single element which has the ID of `leadtxt` and the class of `caption`**?

Comment: It is just an example, sometimes a div holds multiple classes and this also doesnt work in that scenario. Im working with arrays and variables, its all very complex, agian this is just an example. If this works then I can make all the other stuff work to

Comment: I've added further examples as I don't really know where you're having trouble.

Comment: Im accepting your answer for all your time and effort, thank you. But you are just giving me what is in the docs, I already read that and it DOES NOT WORK even though the docs says it should...So your last example does not work, if you don't believe me just set it up your self and you will see what I mean.

Comment: It seems you are right. It doesn't seem to handle those perfectly valid selectors :-( - whenever you ask for more than one thing together, it fails. I can only assume it just isn't very good...

Comment: what about `div` that should not have any class or id. how can I select them?

Answer (score 1):

Mark Embling is right that his approach should work, but it doesn't because simple just isn't a very good library.
Either of these should work:

```
$html->find('div#leadtxt[class="caption"]', 0);
$html->find('div.caption[id="leadtxt"]', 0);
```

Alternatively you could consider switching to phpquery